# How to compile sass without gulp and laravel-elixir [ FIX ]

Tags: php, node.js, laravel, npm, sass

If You get an error like [this](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/issues/1072):

[image: Error]

> **Then you are in the right place :)**

Answer (score 1):

Firstly first you have to delete the node_modules folder from your project.
To do this, type these commands :

> Please note, copy the module name before deleting the package.json :)

1. rm -rf node_modules
2. rm -rf package-lock.json
3. rm -rf package.json
4. npm cache clean

Now you will need a new package.json by doing this you need this command:

- npm init

hit enter until the command-line comes back.

Now you need to install **Node-Sass** to do this, type this command:

- npm install node-sass

if there's a problem with permissions try it with sudo, like this:

- sudo npm install node-sass

After installing **Node-sass** you need to write **Node-sass** command, go to the package.json file and you will see something like this:

```
{
  "name": "blog",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Bla Bla Bla Bla ...",
  "main": "gulpfile.js",
  "directories": {
    "test": "tests"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.13.1"
  }
}
```

In the scripts section add an scss command, under the test command, like this:

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
  "scss": "node-sass resources/assets/sass -o public/css"
}
```

you can use --watch option, like this:

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
  "scss": "node-sass --watch resources/assets/sass -o public/css"
}
```

Which means to watch a directory or file if there's a change, in other terms, it will compile all .scss files every time you hit `CTRL + S` or `CMD + S`.

And Finally, run the script:

- npm run scss

Many thanks to **[Zviad Sichinava](https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/watch-and-compile-sass-in-five-quick-steps--cms-28275)**.

Learn More about [node-sass](https://github.com/sass/node-sass).